# Paypal API Integration using python

Tags: python

I want to know How to integrate any API using python? I want to integrate Paypal using python. What is the correct way to integrate any api, for example Paypal, Stripe etc. How to get basic info like gateway URL and response?

Comment: You need to do your research and come up with code. Python documentation is where you can start. DoGoogle for related information. SOF forum can help you with specific issues in the code.

Comment: please checkout https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/install/

Answer (score 2):

I do not have enough reputation to comment so I'll post this as an answer instead.

You are looking for [PayPal-Python](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK).

Anywho, for simple requests/response you can do something like this:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass")
print(response.status_code)
```

For querying an api in python you can do something like this:

```
parameters = {"lat": 40.71, "lon": -74}

# Make a get request with the parameters.
response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json", params=parameters)

# Print the content of the response (the data the server returned)
print(response.content)
```

This is the same as doing:

```
response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json?lat=40.71&lon=-74")
print(response.content)
```

As you will notice, you're working with JSON data, so you would probably want to use the json module as such:

```
import requests
import json

parameters = {"lat": 40.71, "lon": -74}
response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/iss-pass.json", params=parameters)

data = response.json()
# will return a python dictionary
print(type(data))
print(data)
# save it using the json module
with open('myData.json','w') as my_json:
    json.dump(data,my_json)
```

Anyway, that is the basics. As you can see, it is all about hitting the right end-points with the correct parameters.[PayPal helps you with this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/). The PayPal-Python SDK, is just using the same information provided by PayPal to provide you as a developer a simple rest api.

Comment: This affirmation is not quite correct `As you will notice, you're working with JSON data, so you would probably want to use the json module as such:`- In the code you're importing the json package `import json`, but you're not using it in fact. By reading your answer, I learnt that `requests.get` accepts a dict of params (thanks for that).

Comment: My point was that now you can handle the data as a dictionary and as it is json data, you will most likely want to do stuff regarding the json module (that is why i wrote 'PROBABLY'). Anyway, thanks for your observation, I extended my example to add something to do with the json module